# PowerShell Script to Gather System Temperature

Tags: powershell, physical-environment

Does anyone have a PowerShell Script they use to gather system temperature information?  This is not to replace external sensors, just another way to monitor the health of a system from a temperature perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to get what you need using WMIC: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Open Hardware Monitor Report](https://github.com/jochenwezel/openhardwaremonitor/releases)

I've used it inside Powershell, there is a pending merge request with the original project here:

https://github.com/openhardwaremonitor/openhardwaremonitor/pull/1115